# In Python, how to count a number of elements in multiple columns that are higher than element in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I like to count elements in columns 1 to 3 that are greater than elements in column 0. For example, I have a dataframe as below.

```
    a   b   c     d
0  50  60  40  20.0
1  40  10  30  40.0
2  30  40  20  35.0
3  20   0  30  25.0
4  10   5  40   NaN
```

And I want to count elements in columns b,c,d that are greater than element in column a. So the result should be as below.

```
    a   b   c     d  count
0  50  60  40  20.0      1
1  40  10  30  40.0      0
2  30  40  20  35.0      2
3  20   0  30  25.0      2
4  10   5  40   NaN      1
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome, have you researched how to compare two series in pandas? Do you have any code that needs improvement? If so, you can edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) along `axis=0` to create a boolean mask then use [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) along `axis=1` on this mask to get the `count`:

```
df['count'] = df[['b', 'c', 'd']].gt(df['a'], axis=0).sum(1)
```

Result:

```
    a   b   c     d  count
0  50  60  40  20.0      1
1  40  10  30  40.0      0
2  30  40  20  35.0      2
3  20   0  30  25.0      2
4  10   5  40   NaN      1
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of the columns involved, we can do the comparison and convert the boolean results to int (1 for True, 0 for False):

```
def greater_value(df, reference, column):
    return (df[column] > df[reference]).astype(int)
```

And then add up the results:

```
df['count'] = greater_value(df, 'a', 'b') + greater_value(df, 'a', 'c') + greater_value(df, 'a', 'd')
```

Or generalize across a supplied set of column names:

```
def count_greater(df, reference, *columns):
    return sum(greater_value(df, reference, column) for column in columns)

df['count'] = count_greater(df, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```